# C# Identity Get memeber from GUID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-identity

I have a table that stores the GUID of the last person to make a change.

I would like to display the Users Email address in my view instead of the GUID, however I can not workout how to do this either in the view or controller.

The GUID exists in the AspNetUsers table, and I could just query the table directly but that seems wrong. So how do I get a member object from a GUID?

I'm obviously missing something, but not sure what.

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

Edit:

The Field AddedBy is where I store the UserID

Currently to get the GUID, I do the following: So either in the controler or view I need to find the member with that ID. And get thier email address

Controller Code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        return View(db.PriceChanges.ToList());
    }
```

View Code:

```
<td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AddedBy)                                                          
    </td>
```

Comment: is this some sort of default table in an ASP.NET project?  how is the GUID displaying?  we would need to see the code that is actually showing the GUID

Comment: I've added the code, AspNetUsers is created automatically as part of AspNet.Identity. I just need to know where I need to pass the UserID to get a user object from AspNet.Identity

Comment: Try `UserManager` `FindByIdAsync`

Comment: Are the PriceChanges part of the same DbContext as the Identity user tables? So that it is actually a foreign key constraint you have between user and price change?